# Storing 1 MB byte array as session attribute

Tags: java, session, httpsession

I am running a Java web app.

A user uploads a file (max 1 MB) and I would like to store that file until the user completes an entire process (which consists of multiple requests).

Is it ok to store the file as a byte array in the session until the user completes the entire process? Or is this expensive in terms of resources used?

The reason I am doing this is because I ultimately store the file on an external server (eg aws s3) but I only want to send it to that server if the whole process is completed.

Another option would be to just write the file to a temporary file on my server. However, this means I would need to remove the file in case the user exits the website. But it seems excessive for me to add code to the `SessionDestroyed` method in my `SessionListener` which removes the file if it’s just for this one particular case (ie: sessions are created throughout my entire application where I don’t need to check for temp files).

Thanks.

Comment: "Or is this expensive in terms of resources used?" it takes about 1MB of memory resources.

Comment: What is the actual question here? If you can store 1MB in memory?

Comment: @Kayaman is this ok for a web app? Or is there a better approach to the problem.

Comment: Only you can answer that question. I don't even know how much memory you have.

Comment: @Chewtoy yes, I’d like to know if this is a reasonable approach for solving the issue I described. Or if it’s bad practice to store this much memory in the session.

Comment: @Kayaman I have 4GB of memory.i don’t anticipate many users using this particular feature frequently... but I thought there may be some general advice to stay away from behavior like this (or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Maybe Yes, maybe No

Certainly it is reasonable to store such data in memory in a session if that fits your deployment constraints.

Remember that each user has their own session. So if all of your users have such a file in their [session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)), then you must multiply to calculate the approximate impact on memory usage.

If you exceed the amount of [memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) available at runtime, there will be consequences. Your [Servlet container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) may [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) less-used sessions to storage, which is a problem if you’ve not programmed *all* of your objects to support serialization.  The [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) and OS may use a swap file to move contents out of real memory as part of the [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) system. That swapping may impact or even cripple performance.

You must consider your runtime deployment constraints, which you did not disclose. Are you running on a Raspberry Pi or inexpensive little cloud server with little memory available?  Or will you run on an enterprise-class server with half a [terabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terabyte) of RAM? Do you have 3 users, 300, or 30,000? You need to crunch the numbers and determine your needs, and maybe do some runtime profiling to see actual usage.

For example… I write web apps using the [*Vaadin Framework*](http://www.Vaadin.com/), a sophisticated package for creating desktop-style apps within a web browser.  Being [Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet)-based, Vaadin maintains a complete representation of each user’s entire work data on the server-side in the Servlet session. Multiplied by the number of users, and depending on the complexity of the app, this may require much memory. So I need to account for this and run my server on sufficient hardware with [64-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) Java tuned to run with a large amount of memory. Or take other approaches such [load-balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) across multiple servers with [sticky sessions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)#Persistence).

Fortunately, RAM is quite cheap nowadays. And 64-bit hardware with large physical support for [RAM modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_module), 64-bit operating systems, and 64-bit JVM implementations ( [*Azul*](https://www.azul.com/), [others](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) ) are all readily available.

Comment: just curious, which PAAS do you use? I'm considering using Jelastic with Vaadin.

Comment: @Mathomatic I have deployed Vaadin apps on macOS on Mac mini computers in a colo, which has turned out to be extremely reliable. And currently I’m exploring the use of DigitalCloud.com virtual machines running FreeBSD. But Vaadin is just a Servlet, albeit one large complex Servlet. So you should be able to use any environment supporting Java Servlet technology [web container](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container), as long as it has enough RAM for your app & users.

Comment: How do you know how much RAM is needed?